# Relative paths to DLL's for the built app

Tags: visual-studio, reference, visual-studio-2012, relative-path

I wonder if it's possible to make something like this...

I have a project in `VS2012` that uses two referenced `VS` projects (`DLLs` are being created during compilation) and some other `DLLs` (external libraries etc.). Now I want to clean up my compilation and place `DLLs` in two folders: e.g. `Internals` and `Externals`.

How to make it possible? The problem is that my compiled `.exe` app file wants the `DLLs` to be placed in the main folder (near to it) - so if it needs to load the library from `DLL` it crashes...

I tried to find something in the web, but ppl only ask about copying `DLLs` from the reference folders into the output folder. But that's not what I want to do:/

Comment: at a minimum, you can use a custom build step to copy the DLLs where ever you want

Comment: Yes, I can copy, but the problem is my .exe won't find it...

Comment: The exact question should look like "How to set relative DLL references for my app?"

Comment: can you set the PATH environment variable prior to running your app?

Comment: When I set PATH variable and add a path to my DLLs, will it work? Even if yes, it's really bad solution and I keep looking for something "nice" :)

Comment: Yes, if your DLLs are on your path, your EXE will find them a run. You say it's a bad solution, but that's how for EXE finds all of those system DLLs and visual studio redistributables.

Comment: Yes, but .NET is a framework which should be visible for all the apps using it. And what if I want to use `My.dll` in the one project and and a completely different `My.dll` for the second project? Paths will be different, too - so I can add them both to PATH variable, but apps will have some problems and probably use first one listed. How do ppl solve this problem in their apps? I can be wrong, but I don't think the modify PATH var. Please, correct me if I'm wrong. Btw. thx for being interested in my problem!:)

Comment: And the second issue, what if I move my app folder somewhere? Then I need to modify my PATH var:/

Comment: are your DLL's all .NET assemblies? If so, you could sign them and put them in the Global Assembly Cache. Instructions are here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815808

Comment: Not exactly, there are some custom libraries downloaded from Google code. I don't believe it's such a problem, many programs have defined folder structure after installation (and DLLs are placed in some folder e.g. "bin").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution. I need to add a new item `app.config` and specify `privatePaths`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="InternalsFolder;ExternalsFolder" />
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```